# Как наследоваться от модуля?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Файл `m1.py`:

```
x = 1
def y():
    return 2
# ... Много переменных и функций ...
```

Как сделать так, чтобы класс `Foo` содержал в себе все, что содержит модуль `m1`?

Пробовал так:

Файл `m2.py`:

```
import m1

class Foo(m1):
    pass
```

Но получил ошибку:

```
TypeError: module.__init__() takes at most 2 arguments (3 given)
```

Comment: Если не секрет для чего это необходимо?

Comment: @Avernial, есть очень большой класс. Я решил разбить его на модули без классов, чтобы было проще ориентироваться в коде.

Comment: Не проще ли тогда работать прямо с модулями или разбить большой класс на несколько меньших.

Comment: @Avernial, согласен. Так будет проще.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы все из модуля стало доступно в вашем классе, можно обновить словарь самого объекта.

```
import math

class Foo(object):

    def __init__(self):
         self.__dict__.update(math.__dict__)

f = Foo() 
print(dir(f))
print(f.sqrt(10))
```

Так же сработает вариант предложенный Александром, но в таком варианте вы не увидите содержимое пока явно не обратитесь к требуемой функции или переменной.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте вот так:

```
import m1


class Foo(object):

    def __getattr__(self, item):
        return m1.__dict__[item]
```